# Scikit-learn with a mix of text and numeric data

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have my data available to me as a CSV, in the following format (this is a sample line, one of a few ten thousand)

```
FEIPDDVPLPAGWEMAKTSSGQRYFLNHIDQTTTWQDPRKGPPPY,0,0,13,0,0,4,12,16
```

Each text string is similar to this kind of string; same for the numeric ones.

I'm looking for a way to predict the numbers based on correlation with text.

Is there any way to do this in scikit-learn?

Comment: what is the meaning of the text? It is quite hard to answer this question without more context. We have to understand the meaning of 'on correlation'

Comment: The text is meant to represent a protein's primary structure; the other values are values associated with that protein

Comment: Can the numbers have any value or does are the possible values fixed (i.e. clustering / classification problem)?

Comment: @d909 is the size of the protein string the same for all entries?

Comment: @a_guest the numbers can have any value; the range is not that great and they're only integers.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev the protein strings vary in length.

Comment: sounds like the letters are nominal (as opposed to ordinal) categorical data... is there any downside to just converting them to integers and proceeding from there?

Comment: @Lee88 i suppose the issue would then be dealing w having more letters in the alphabet than integers 0-9 (although it could be two digit) -- the letters are essentially the equivalent to different colors in an image. I picture a long image with one pixel dots of different colors for each letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to generate some aggregate functions on the string and use those as features to predict the remaining values. Examples of simple aggregate functions could be number of occurrences of each letter, length, first letter, last letter, most common letter, possibly number of transitions between each pair of letters etc.

This is the best I can think of without having background knowledge for the specific area.